# Silverlight: Data changes are not transported to controls in external assemblies

Tags: silverlight, charts

I have an Silverlight application that loads controls from external assemblies dynamically which works fine so far. The loaded control (a chart in this case) also gets the right datacontext (implicit by its parent) and displays its data correct.

But when I change some of the data in a binded datagrid I expect the chart to be updated as well. In fact it isn't. If I add another "local" chart it works but not on my chart from the external assembly. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is difficult to answer because I'm not sure that a datagrid can affect a chart. Also why to load the chart control dynamically if it can be referenced in straight way?

Comment: We have users working with Blend which have to create/change Gui after the application is deployed. So we can exchange parts of the Gui on the fly.

Comment: But you can use existing controls and load styles. Also the problem can be in xaml files and `ResourceDictionary` elements. Try to change the `Source` property to the full name with assembly, like `<ResourceDictionary Source="/MyAssembly;component/Styles.xaml"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I really don't know why this doesn't work. So I changed my approach and began to load Xaml-files now instead of assemblies which works like charm.